# SignalR trigger is disabled due to 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection string is not set or invalid. Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr, signalr-hub

I am getting this error on running Azure Function app with the SignalR Serverlesshub class.

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'GetWnsetdsbyani'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService: SignalR trigger is disabled due to 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection string is not set or invalid. Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.309Z] Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.310Z]
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.311Z] Headers:
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.311Z] Server: Azurite-Blob/3.14.1
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.312Z] Date: Sat, 29 Jul 2023 21:25:20 GMT
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.313Z] Connection: keep-alive
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.313Z] Keep-Alive: REDACTED
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.314Z] Content-Length: 0
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.315Z]
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.315Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.DownloadAsync(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String range, String leaseId, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentMD5, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentCRC64, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.316Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Int64 startOffset, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.316Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreamingInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.317Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.318Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-29T21:25:21.318Z]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0):

> SignalR trigger is disabled due to 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection string is not set or invalid. Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed

This Error clearly stating that **`AzureWebJobsStorage`**  is not set with the connection string of Storage Account or it is not configured correctly.

To Configure it you follow below:

[image]

It looks like your function app is trying to access local emulator(azurite) still, you need to change it with the Actual Storage account in Azure.

Comment: Thank you! But it is already configured. And this error is on running locally in debug mode.